# How to make docker fail or check version exists

Tags: bash, maven, docker, maven-antrun-plugin

I have maven running a bash to build something with Docker.

```
<plugin>
    ...
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
            <exec executable="${basedir}/generate.sh" failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="${thrift.version}" />
...
```

The bash script runs something like:

```
for file in src/main/thrift/*.thrift; do
    echo "Compiling ${file}"
    docker run {...} thrift:${THRIFT_VERSION} thrift {...}
done
```

My problem is, when Docker can't find the version I'm requesting, it shows an error in console but it doesn't "fail": it just keeps building.

```
 [exec] Compiling src/main/thrift/amsException.thrift
 [exec] docker: Tag 0.9.0 not found in repository docker.io/library/thrift.
 [exec] See 'docker run --help'.
 [exec] Unable to find image 'thrift:0.9.0' locally
```

and consequently maven says

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make Docker throw and error when it can't find the version? My final goal is Maven failing to clean-install when this happens.

Cheers!

Comment: I guess another option would be to previously check whether the version exists, but I would still need to throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `docker run` exit code. If it's not 0, then abort your script.

```
for file in src/main/thrift/*.thrift; do
    echo "Compiling ${file}"
    docker run {...} thrift:${THRIFT_VERSION} thrift {...}
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        exit -1
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can do it in one go, no need for checking `$?`: `if docker run ...; then ...; fi`